# Nuget package is referencing old database context from class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, nuget

I currently have a class library project that contains an ADO.Net database context file and metadata classes for those context models. I'm using the database first approach and have added two new tables and modified one table. I'm able to build the project successfully and reference the new tables in a different project in the same solution but when I create a NuGet package for the Context class library and install the NuGet package in a new project, those new tables are not there and the table that was supposed to be updated is not.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Here are the steps I took to properly package it.

1. Update Assembly Info on project
2. Build Project on Release config
3. Create spec file 'nuget spec'
4. Pack into nupkg using -properties parameter 'nuget pack PROJ.csproj -properties Configuration=Release'

I was able to stumble upon the properties parameter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#replacement-tokens).